# Unexpected nullptr in expansion of variadic template constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Difficult to explain, here a short stand-alone example of what I mean:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::function<void(void)> f_t;

struct A { A(f_t f) { f(); } };
struct B { B(f_t f) { f(); } };
struct C { C(f_t f) { f(); } };

template<typename ... TT>
struct T : TT...
{
    T( ) : TT([this](void) { std::cout << this << std::endl; })...
    {
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    T<A, B, C> t;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x7ffe84574e6f
0
0
```

My class template `T` inherits from its template parameter pack `TT`. Each type of `TT` expects a functor as constructor argument. When I try to pass a functor that captures `this` during the constructor calls, all but the first constructor call of the expansion actually receive a functor that captured `nullptr` as `this`. If I delegate the functor creation to a member function, it works as intended:

```
template<typename ... TT>
struct T : TT...
{
    T( ) : TT(genF())...
    {
    }

    f_t genF( ) { return [this](void) { std::cout << this << std::endl; }; }
};
```

Output:

```
0x7ffefca4e61f
0x7ffefca4e61f
0x7ffefca4e61f
```

(Compiler used is GCC 4.6.3)

What causes this behavior? Is it a compiler bug? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You definitely need to update compiler. C++11 support in gcc 4.6 was incomplete.

Comment: Might be related to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71386 or similar issues. g++ support for pack expansion and lambdas was notoriously poor until 8.x

Comment: I feared as much. Unfortunately I am not in a position where I can switch compilers, so I guess I have to stick to a workaround. Thanks.